# computing p-value with small n

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

As part of the quality-control program for a catalyst manufacturing
line, the raw materials (alumina and a binder) are tested for purity. The process
requires that the purity of the alumina be greater than 85%. A random sample
from a recent shipment of alumina yielded the following results (in %):
$$ 93.2, 87.0, 92.1, 90.1, 87.3, 93.6$$
Using that information, I get that 
$$n = 6, \bar X =.91, S = 0.03$$
A) State the appropriate null and alternative hypotheses.
I have that
$$H_0:\mu_0<.85\space H_1:\mu_0\le.85$$
B)Compute the p-value.
 $$test\space statistic\space t=\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu_0)}{\sigma}=\frac{\sqrt{6}(.91-.85)}{.03} =4.9$$
Since n is sufficiently small, we calculate the t-distribution
Assuming a 5% significance level, and with 5 degrees of freedom
$t_{.025,5} =2.571$ 
C)Should the shipment be accepted? Explain.
The shipment should not be accepted because 2.571< 4.9 which disproves the null hypothesis. We therefore accept the alternative hypothesis

Answer (score 0):

$a)$: The null and alternative hypothesis should be:

$H_0: \mu = 0.85, H_1: \mu > 0.85$

$b)$: It is not necessary to get an exact $P$-value, you can estimate it with $df = n-1 = 6-1 = 5, \alpha = 0.05$, and the test is a one-tail test ( right tail ), then $P$-value $< 0.005 < 0.05 = \alpha $ because $4.9 > 4.032$ which corresponds to the $\alpha = 0.005$ using Triola textbook. Thus we reject $H_0$